# Confusion regarding second part of fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

When $A$ is the area function,we define it by $A(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ and from the first fundamental theorem of calculus we get $A'(x)=f(x)$.Now putting $x=a$,we have $A(a)=0$ since the region has area $0$?But then $A'(a)=0$ which is not equal to $f(a)$ since $f(a)$ doesn't necessarily have to be $0$,isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: Why is $A’(a)=0$?

Comment: Derivative of $0$ is $0$?

Comment: The question is based on a wrong premise, but I consider this a "useful mistake" because you learn more by making and correcting mistakes, and it's an opportunity for more explanation which may help other people as well.

Answer (score 3):

To see where you're thinking wrongly, apply the same logic to the function $A(x)=x$.  (This would be $f(t)=1$ and $a=0$ if you wish to stay within your area-function scenario, but this doesn't really matter.)  Here, $A(0)=0$.  Is the derivative $A'(0)=0$?  No, as $A'(x)=1$ for all $x$.

You are confusing being $0$ (or being constant) at one point with being $0$ (or constant) everywhere.  We take derivatives of *functions* at a point, not derivatives of points at a point.  As the derivative $A'(a)$ is defined by the limit
$$
A'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{A(a+h)-A(a)}{h}
$$
it necessarily must take into account the values of $A(x)$ in a small interval around $a$ (see the numerator), so what $A(x)$ does at *exactly* $a$ and nowhere else is not the entire story.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sure. I made the exact same mistake when I first learned this.